# Azure search service - Soft deletion not working

Tags: azure, search, service, azure-cognitive-search

We have configured index using an azure search service with data source as View in Azure SQL database. View is created based on 4 tables join.  We are using CHANGE TRACKING POLICY : High watermark column, HIGH WATERMARK COLUMN :Rowversion, SOFT DELETE COLUMN: IsDeleted, DELETE MARKER VALUE:"1". My question is- whenever the API is called, should the IsDeleted = 1 records will be fetched? My understanding is- they should not be fetched. Please suggest. In my search result, these records with IsDeleted= 1 are being fetched; what could have gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to verify:

1. The indexer runs on a schedule, so changes to your index won't happen instantly.
2. Verify that the indexer actually succeeds. You can do that directly in Azure portal (open indexers blade for your search service), or programmatically using the [Get Indexer Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946884.aspx) API (or the corresponding.NET SDK API).